How to know how to set the values for ScreenUtil in flutter app
I am learning how to use the Flutter_ScreenUtil 5.9.3 package.
The documentation leaves a lot to the imagination.
I have watched a few YouTube videos regarding how to use this package but they are very short and don't explain how to use the letter extentions of the values.
For example:
Text('Forgot Password', fontSize: 16.r),),

and I have seen this:
Text('Forgot Password', fontSize: 16.sp),),

The documentation does not speak about the r or the sp so how do I know how to use them.
How do I use these things?
Thanks

See the answer to your previous question.  Stop using flutter_screenutil.
